# Referencing Child Views in Included XML

Tags: android, layout, include

I know I can use include/merge to include an XML file in another XML file.  If the included layout contains children and you include several instances of this in the root view, how do you find the ID of each child instance?

For example if the included layout contains a listview, and you include 3 instances of this layout in the root layout, how do you find and reference the 3 listview children?

UPDATE:
For folks reading this thread:  There is actually a much better solution that I have found, and in retrospect its quite obvious.  The problem with getChildAt() is that if you add new views or re-arrange things, this code will either crash or not work since the index of the children has changed, and the class types may not even match anymore.  So not very maintainable.  It turns out that findViewById() works fine if you just drill down a bit further into the layout and if you give each of the includes an ID.  So for example, suppose you have 3 includes in a layout, with ID names "list_container1", "list_container2" and "list_container3".  Each of these includes the same list view XML with the same ID name.  Now instead of trying to find your lists from the root layout, which won't work, find the containers first, then find the lists like this:

```
myRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
container1 = (LinearLayout) myRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_container1);
list1 = (ListView) container1.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
container2 = (LinearLayout) myRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_container2);
list2 = (ListView) container2.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
container3 = (LinearLayout) myRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_container3);
list3 = (ListView) container3.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
```

In the above example, the layout hiearchy is like this (and could be further simplified):

```
LinearLayout
    <include>
        LinearLayout
            ListView
    <include>
        LinearLayout
            ListView
    <include>
        LinearLayout
            ListView
```

Comment: Why would it be different from replacing each include by its actual content ?

Comment: The problem is that all the children have the same ID because you are just literally including them 3 times.  The answer below is the correct one.

Comment: But nothing prevents your from using 3 times the same ID without doing any include. this is an ID issue which has nothing to do with include I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your root layout's [`getChildAt(int index)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) method to go to any child.  In fact `findViewById()` simply uses this and `getChildCount()` to loop through all of a layout's child views until one matches the given id.

---

Example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
ListView list1 = (ListView) layout.getChildAt(0);
ListView list2 = (ListView) layout.getChildAt(1);
ListView list3 = (ListView) layout.getChildAt(2);
```

The exact index depends on how you have arranged your layout.

Comment: but, now we use databinding, can we refer to child views with binding.someCHild.someattr?